# Print to DotNetNuke Event Log/Viewer

Tags: c#, vb.net, dotnetnuke

For debugging purposes, how can I print to the event log/viewer in DotNetNuke, using VB.NET or C#?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From http://www.ventrian.com/Resources/Articles/tabid/213/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/330/Logging-to-the-EventLog.aspx (just the relevant part of the article):

> Using the event log in code is quite
>   simple, the code is as follows:-
>
> First, create an instance of the
>   EventLogViewer...
>
> ```
> Dim objEventLog As New DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.EventLogController
> ```
>
> Next, log the event you wish to
>   trap...
>
> ```
> objEventLog.AddLog("Sample Message",
>     "Something Interesting Happened!",
>     PortalSettings,
>     -1,
>     DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.EventLogController.EventLogType.ADMIN_ALERT)
> ```
>
> Now, when this code is run, the event
>   log entry should appear in admin ->
>   log viewer! You can customise these
>   type of events, whether they be admin,
>   host, item updated, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Also, if you want to add more data to the log, you can use LogInfo class to add events to the log.

```
Dim eventLog As EventLogController
eventLog = New EventLogController()

Dim logInfo As DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.LogInfo
logInfo = New LogInfo()
logInfo.LogUserID = UserId
logInfo.LogPortalID = PortalSettings.PortalId
logInfo.LogTypeKey = EventLogController.EventLogType.ADMIN_ALERT.ToString()
logInfo.AddProperty("PropertyName1", propertyValue1)
logInfo.AddProperty("PropertyName2", propertyValue2)

eventLog.AddLog(logInfo)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the C# version

```
using DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog;

EventLogController eventLog = new EventLogController();
DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.LogInfo logInfo = new LogInfo();
logInfo.LogUserID = UserId;
logInfo.LogPortalID = PortalSettings.PortalId;
logInfo.LogTypeKey=EventLogController.EventLogType.ADMIN_ALERT.ToString();
logInfo.AddProperty("KeyWord=", txtSearch.Text.Trim());
logInfo.AddProperty("KeyWordLike=", myParams);
eventLog.AddLog(logInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities;
using DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog;
public static void DnnEventLogMsg(string msg)
{
    EventLogController eventLog = new EventLogController();
    DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.LogInfo logInfo = new LogInfo();
    PortalSettings ps = PortalController.Instance.GetCurrentPortalSettings();
    UserInfo userInfo = UserController.Instance.GetCurrentUserInfo();
    logInfo.LogUserID = userInfo.UserID;
    logInfo.LogPortalID = ps.PortalId;
    logInfo.LogTypeKey = EventLogController.EventLogType.ADMIN_ALERT.ToString();
    logInfo.AddProperty("Atena3 Message", msg);
    eventLog.AddLog(logInfo);
}
```